# My ajax method is not working,

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, cordova

In console log getting the bellow message
Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing
So I checked few stack overflow solution but not able to resolve some one can help me to resolve it.

```
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function () 
    {
    var save_temp = {
                 "token": "e2c420d928d4bf8ce0ff2ec19b371514"
                  };
             var comment_data = JSON.stringify(save_temp);

    //alert(comment_data);
    var request = $.ajax({
       url: "http://vyhub.com/irmtapi/dailyreport/checkReport",
       type: "POST",
       data:comment_data,
       contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
       dataType: 'json',
    });

    request.done(function(msg)
    {
      // $("#log").html( msg );
    alert(msg)
    });

    request.fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus) {
       alert( "Request failed: " + textStatus );
    });

    });

    </script>
```

Comment: You can't do anything from the client side. This is an issue in the server side. Kindly read stuff from [**Enable CORS**](http://enable-cors.org/).

Comment: No in client side also i am getting the same error

Comment: I was using 192.168.1.9/irmtapi/ the same issue

Comment: I just gave you a link to enable the CORS. Did you even check that? What's the server are you using?

Comment: Ok will check now

Comment: Which server are you using?

Comment: I tried from local using lamp and in live server also

Comment: For LAMP Server, you need to use either a `.htaccess` solution by giving `Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"`. You need to enable the `mod_headers` by using `a2enmod headers`. Or use `header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");` to set the right headers.

Comment: but I dont know where to add it

Comment: More information for [Apache Server](http://enable-cors.org/server_apache.html) and [PHP](http://enable-cors.org/server_php.html).

Comment: Check out the detailed answer.

Answer (score 1):

This is clearly a problem with the server side code, which doesn't send the right headers to allow the Cross Origin Request Sharing. You need to [enable CORS](http://enable-cors.org/) through two ways in Apache Server with PHP.

**Method 1:** Using Apache Server's settings.

Using Apache's `.htaccess`, you can enable the CORS by adding the following line:

```
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
```

For this to work, you need to make sure that the `mod_headers` module is enabled. You can enable this by using `sudo a2enmod headers`. You need sudo permissions for this. Also, you need to restart Apache Server after changing the configuration by using `sudo service apache2 reload`.

**Method 2:** Using PHP Code.

Alternatively, if you don't have much control over the server management, you can enable it in your script that responds to your request. Just add this at the top of the PHP file, so that the browser is allowed AJAX Access:

```
<?php
  header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
```

Let me know if you have any further questions. For more information, please find the references below:

- [Enable CORS in Apache Server](http://enable-cors.org/server_apache.html)
- [Enable CORS in PHP Script](http://enable-cors.org/server_php.html)